# Adding password protection to user view in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I know wordpress have a password-protect feature that can be set for each post and page.
Do any of you know if this feature can be added to viewing a user profile? (Set pw for each user, and not as a global password).

Example:

A visitor clicks on "user1" -> "Please enter password to view users profile".